# display months name in angular NVD3 multicharts

Tags: angularjs, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

I'm trying to display the months name to make a multi-chart graph that will analyze the data for this year and the previous one.
I was trying to do that using ticks.
here is a [punker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ie4SCZ?p=preview) where i'm trying to do that, but I'm not able to display months name, it shows always January.
is there a way to do it differently?
which is the best way and how to fix that?

```
xAxis: {
    axisLabel: 'Months',
    showMaxMin: true,
    tickFormat: function(d) {
      return d3.time.format('%B')(new Date(d))
    },
    ticks:12,
    tickValues:['Jan','Fev','Mars','Avr','Mai','Juin','Juil','Aout','Sept','Oct','Nov','Dec']
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do that using tickformat, and to get that displayed in the tooltip you need to use the `interactiveLayer` options to get that correctly displayed.
here is a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dlsojZnwXVz0d9RZK6tj?p=preview).